# What database hostname should I use for ASP.NET apps with docker-compose?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker-compose

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET project (based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) tutorial) using Visual Studio for Mac, and need to run Docker containers for the web app and the SQL Server database.

Using the following `docker-compose.yaml`, both containers run successfully and I can load the web app landing page at http://localhost:5000:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  razorpagesmovie:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}razorpagesmovie
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RazorPagesMovie/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mssql

  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "L0ngpassword"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

The connection string in `appsettings.json` is

```
Server=<host>,1433;Database=Movies;User=sa;Password=L0ngpassword;
```

However, I don't know what value to use for the hostname:

1. If I hardcode my machine's IP address, then both the web app AND `dotnet ef database ...` calls executed on my local shell can connect to the database - until my IP changes
2. If I use `localhost` then only `dotnet ef database ...` commands executed on my local shell can connect to the database
3. If I use `mssql`, then only the web app container can connect to the database

Is there a more robust approach than hardcoding my IP?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your appsettings.json file has json key `ConnectionString`.

You can add an environment variable for connection string to that container. Use DB_IP or put service name `mssql` of the DB container.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  razorpagesmovie:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}razorpagesmovie
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RazorPagesMovie/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - ConnectionString=${DB_IP:-Server=mssql;Database=Movies;User=sa;Password=L0ngpassword} 
    depends_on:
      - mssql

  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "L0ngpassword"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```